# How i can set My start point with my end point in google Maps By Intent?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers, google-maps-urls

I can set my end point here. How  can I set the start point with it?

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google launched new API: Google Maps URLs

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

This API allows to create

> a universal, cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps and perform searches, get directions and navigation, and display map views and panoramic images.

From now on you can use something like

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Space+Needle+Seattle+WA&destination=Pike+Place+Market+Seattle+WA&dir_action=navigate");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use below snippet:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&saddr=" + currentlatLng.latitude + "," + currentlatLng.longitude + "&daddr=" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude+ "&mode=driving";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_OPEN_GOOGLE_MAP);
```

Comment: Google recommends using the Google Maps URLs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Comment: @xomena  in my scenario I have to use this for opening Google map app with lat lng.

Comment: Perfect, the new and blessed by Google way is Google Maps URLs. Have a look at the docs, these URLs are cross-platform, so native apps can understand them easily. The same URL will work with Android, iOS or desktop browser.

Comment: @xomena ok i will check it,